# How to fill StackLayout to the end with image background and remove spacing between grid using xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to stretch a picture of the whole StackLayout but it stretches to the middle. I also want to reduce the distance between the rows and columns in the grid.
My code:

```
<Frame
                   BorderColor="White"
                   Margin="10,0,10,0"
                   CornerRadius="10"
                   HasShadow="True"
                   BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                 <RelativeLayout>
        <Image
            
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                   Property=Height,
                                                                   Factor=0.5}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                  Property=Width,
                                                                  Factor=1}"
            Source="https://www.4freephotos.com/medium/batch/Scattered-clouds276.jpg" />
        <StackLayout>
                    <Label x:Name="DateTimeForecast1"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               FontSize="14"/>
                    <Label x:Name="DateTimeForecast2"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               FontSize="14"/>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                      Padding="0,0,0,0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image x:Name="IconForecast11"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].WeatherForecast[0].DescriptionForecast}"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               FontSize="14"/>

                        <Image x:Name="IconForecast12"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <Label x:Name="AvgTempForecastDay1"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               FontSize="14"/>

                        <Image x:Name="IconForecast13"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.Column="2"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].WindForecast.WindForecastValue, StringFormat='{0:0}m/s'}"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="2"
                               FontSize="14"/>

                        <Image x:Name="IconForecast14"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.Column="3"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].CloudsForecast.CloudsForecastValue, StringFormat='{0:0}%'}" 
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="3"
                               FontSize="14"/>

                        <Image x:Name="IconForecast15"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.Column="4"/>
                        <Label x:Name="ChanceOfRainForecast1" 
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="4"
                               FontSize="14"/>
                    

                        <Image x:Name="IconForecast5Days1"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Grid.Row="2"
                               Grid.Column="0"/>

                        <Image x:Name="IconForecast5Days2"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Grid.Row="2"
                               Grid.Column="1"/>

                        <Image x:Name="IconForecast5Days3"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Grid.Row="2"
                               Grid.Column="2"/>

                        <Image x:Name="IconForecast5Days4"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Grid.Row="2"
                               Grid.Column="3"/>

                        <Image x:Name="IconForecast5Days5"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Grid.Row="2"
                               Grid.Column="4"/>

                        <Label Text="Feels like"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="3"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               FontSize="14"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].MainForecasts.FeelsLikeForecast, StringFormat='{0:0}°C'}" 
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="4"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               FontSize="14"/>

                        <Label Text="Min °C"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="3"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               FontSize="14"/>
                        <Label x:Name="MinTempForecastDay1" 
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="4"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               FontSize="14"/>

                        <Label Text="Max °C"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="3"
                               Grid.Column="2"
                               FontSize="14"/>
                        <Label x:Name="MaxTempForecastDay1" 
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="4"
                               Grid.Column="2"
                               FontSize="14"/>

                        <Label Text="Rain"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="3"
                               Grid.Column="3"
                               FontSize="14"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].RainForecast.RainForecastValue, StringFormat='{0}mm'}" 
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="4"
                               Grid.Column="3"
                               FontSize="14"/>

                        <Label Text="Snow"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="3"
                               Grid.Column="4"
                               FontSize="14"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].SnowForecast.SnowForecastValue, StringFormat='{0}mm'}" 
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="4"
                               Grid.Column="4"
                               FontSize="14"/>
                    

                        <Image x:Name="IconForecast5Days26"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Grid.Row="5"
                               Grid.Column="0"/>

                        <Image x:Name="IconForecast5Days27"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Grid.Row="5"
                               Grid.Column="1"/>

                        <Image x:Name="IconForecast5Days28"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Grid.Row="5"
                               Grid.Column="2"/>

                        <Image x:Name="IconForecast5Days29"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Grid.Row="5"
                               Grid.Column="3"/>

                        <Image x:Name="IconForecast5Days30"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Grid.Row="5"
                               Grid.Column="4"/>

                        <Label Text="Humidity"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="6"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               FontSize="14"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].MainForecasts.HumidityForecast, StringFormat='{0:0}%'}" 
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="7"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               FontSize="14"/>

                        <Label Text="Pressure"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="6"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               FontSize="14"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].MainForecasts.PressureForecast, StringFormat='{0:0}mb'}" 
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="7"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               FontSize="14"/>

                        <Label Text="Ground"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="6"
                               Grid.Column="2"
                               FontSize="14"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].MainForecasts.PressureGroundLevelForecast, StringFormat='{0:0}mb'}" 
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="7"
                               Grid.Column="2"
                               FontSize="14"/>

                        <Label Text="Sea Level"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="6"
                               Grid.Column="3"
                               FontSize="14"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].MainForecasts.SeaLevelForecast, StringFormat='{0:0}mb'}" 
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="7"
                               Grid.Column="3"
                               FontSize="14"/>

                        <Label Text="Direction"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="6"
                               Grid.Column="4"
                               FontSize="14"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].WindForecast.WindDirectionForecastValue, StringFormat='{0:0}°'}" 
                               Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Grid.Row="7"
                               Grid.Column="4"
                               FontSize="14"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
              </RelativeLayout>
            </Frame>
```

With this code the image itself is stretched to the middle of the StackLayout.
I will attach a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of StackLayout]

It also makes an ugly impression on me that there is a huge distance between the rows and columns themselves. Can you give an example of how to reduce the distance between the lines and how to stretch the picture of the whole StackLayout

Comment: Sorry my bad, see the rows. They have too much spacing

Comment: Have you tried seting RowSpacing on a Grid or Spacing on a StackLayout ?

Comment: I try with rowspacing=“0” in the grid and spacing=“0” in the StackLayout but this not worked for me 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to stretch a picture of the whole StackLayout but it stretches to the middle.

Set the image's height same as the parent layout .

```
 <Image     Aspect="AspectFill"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                   Property=Height,
                                                                   Factor=1}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                  Property=Width,
                                                                  Factor=1}"
            Source="https://www.4freephotos.com/medium/batch/Scattered-clouds276.jpg" />
```

> I also want to reduce the distance between the rows and columns in the grid. My code:

Set `RowDefinition.Height` as `auto` , `*` will occupy the whole space with all rows .

```
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Works great ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As Cole mentioned before, use "auto" instead of "*" and maybe more rows will help you to achieve what youre looking for.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           ...
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```